# SQL ORDER BY variable parameter

Tags: php, sql, sql-order-by

I can't find how to use a variable as a parameter of the ORDER BY selector : the following code doesn't work.

```
$orderBy = 'number';
$q = $instanceBDD->prepare('SELECT * FROM operations ORDER BY :orderBy ASC', 
                           array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$q->execute(array('orderBy' => $orderBy));
```

whereas

```
$q = $instanceBDD->prepare('SELECT * FROM operations ORDER BY number ASC',
                   array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$q->execute();
```

works.

Since I'd like to put this code in a function with $orderBy as a parameter, it would be really convenient to find a way to tackle this problem...

Comment: You could create a stored procedure where you pass in the name of the column that you wish to order by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can :

- Use placeholders in an order by clause
- Bind column names : you can only bind values -- or variables, and have their value injected in the prepared statement.

You can use just variables tho, like

```
$orders=array("name","price","qty");
$key=array_search($_GET['sort'],$orders));
$order=$orders[$key];
$instanceBDD->prepare("SELECT * FROM operations ORDER BY '$order' ASC');
```

Answer (score 1):

Whats wrong with directly putting it int the string?

```
$q = $instanceBDD->prepare('SELECT * FROM operations ORDER BY '.$orderBy.' ASC',
    array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
```

**EDIT**: Of course `$orderBy` has to be escape to avoid injections (`PDO::quote()`).

Comment: That opens one up for a SQL Injection Attack